# htaccess DirectoryIndex on subdomain not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, directoryindex

I have a subdomain (like subdomain.domain.com) set up on my webserver. The main site is in 'httpdocs' and the subdomain's files are in the folder 'subdomain' on the same level as 'httpdocs'. There is no .htaccess file in 'httpdocs'.
I have .htaccess file in the folder 'subdomain' with:

> DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php

What I want is to open index.html first when I call htpp://subdomain.domain.com in a browser. But I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Is there a way to adapt the .htaccess file to achieve this or maybe a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the output from Apache's error log?

Comment: [Mon Feb 18 12:29:04 2013] [alert] [client 37.188.77.31] /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomain/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbfDirectoryIndex', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 0):

A 500 Internal Server Error could be caused by having incorrect permissions on your .htaccess file.

```
chmod 644 .htaccess
```

if I understand your directory structure correctly as being ~/httpdocs/subdomain/ you will also need a rewrite rule. The following should work.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/subdomain/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
.htaccess permissions are correct (644)
The directory structure is different: ~/subdomain is on the same level as ~/httpdocs

Answer (score 0):

According to the message in your error log, your `.htaccess` file has a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark. Try saving it as plain ASCII.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is the problem. When I edit the same file with f.i. php_flag display_errors 'off' there is no error.